# How does the index of this subgroup is a power of 2?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lattice-orders

I am reading an article about *coset codes* (for answering this question having knowledge about these codes and lattice theory is **not** necessary) which are defined by $(\Lambda ,\Lambda ',C)$ in which $\Lambda$ is an $N$- dimensional Lattice Constellation (an $N$ dimensional lattice is a group under ordinary $N$ tuples addition), $\Lambda '$ is its sub-lattice and $C$ is an encoder. It has been said that in these codes we are generally interested in binary lattices, and it means that for some $n$ we have : $Z^{N}/\Lambda /\Lambda '/2^{n}Z^{N}$, in which $2^{n}Z^{N}$ is the lattice of all $N$ tuples of integer multiples of $2^{n}$. It has said that from the above relation we conclude that the index of $\Lambda '$ in $\Lambda$ is a power of $2$ which I cannot figure it out. Can anyone explain why it is a power of $2$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$[Z^{N}:2^{n}Z^{N}]=[Z^{N}:\Lambda][\Lambda:\Lambda '][\Lambda ':2^{n}Z^{N}]$

and we know $[Z^{N}:2^{n}Z^{N}]=2^{nN}$, hence we conclude

$[\Lambda:\Lambda '] | 2^{nN}$

so it must be a power of $2$

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it using the check mark under the vote count.

Comment: @user215721 I wanted to check mark it but it said that this action is possible after 2 days

Answer (score 2):

Hint: index is transitive, i.e. $[G:K]=[G:H][H:K]$.

Comment: Yes, I know this theorem, but how can you prove the problem with this theorem? perhaps you will say $|\frac{\Lambda}{\Lambda '}|$ $=|\frac{\Lambda}{2^{n}Z^{N}}|$ $\times |\frac{2^{n}Z^{N}}{\Lambda '}|$, but so what?

Comment: (+1) AMIR, we also have $[\Bbb{Z}^N:2^n\Bbb{Z}^N]=2^{nN}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I know this lemma as well, but I cannot proceed to the solution via these lemmas

Comment: Did you not use transitivity?
$$[\Bbb{Z}^N:2^n\Bbb{Z}^N]=[\Bbb{Z}^n:\Lambda][\Lambda:\Lambda']
[\Lambda':2^n\Bbb{Z}^N].$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes. I thought about that

Comment: @AMIR So you know that $2^{nN}$ is a multiple of $[\Lambda:\Lambda']$... do you really think a power of $2$ could be a multiple of anything other than a power of $2$?

Comment: @anon WOW, thank you very much, I did not pay attention to it, thanks again